# R subset columns that meets a condition of zero ratio

Tags: r, subset, multiple-columns, zero

I have a dataset named df,

Here I want to get the columns (make a new dataset with them), that have a zero ratio of > %50

```
df_new <- get columns where zero_ratio> %50
```

could you support?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `colMeans` :

```
df_new <- df[, colMeans(df == 0, na.rm = TRUE) > 0.5]
```

---

With a reproducible example :

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1, 2, 0, 1, 3), b = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1), c = 0)
df_new <- df[, colMeans(df == 0, na.rm = TRUE) > 0.5]
df_new

#  b c
#1 0 0
#2 0 0
#3 1 0
#4 0 0
#5 1 0
```

Comment: it returns "undefined columns selected" in my big datamart (but I already have columns meeting on that condition)

Comment: Maybe you are using it incorrectly. Please provide some more information about your data. `dput(head(df))` would be the best way. As I have shown it works for the data that I have in my post.

Comment: my data is huge. no way. still giving the same error...

Comment: @determinator Does my code behave as expected for the data I have in my post?